# Relationship between sets $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,d)$ compact. If $A\subset X$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X$ and $B\subset X$ is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ in $X$, that is $B=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i$ where $B_i$ is $G_{\delta}$ of $X$.
If $B\subset A$, then what is the relationship between $A$ and $B$ ?

It could be said that $B$ is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ in $A$ ?

Answer (score 2):

> It could be said that $B$ is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ in $A$ ?

Yes, because $B=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(B_i\cap A)$.

Comment: Yes. And this is regardless of whether $X$ is compact or metrizable.